# Why is casting the type still necessary even though it has already been assured in this example?

Tags: optimization, casting, kotlin

Today I came across this section in the [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts). Called "smart casts", Kotlin seems to "insert (safe) casts automatically when needed":

> In many cases, one does not need to use explicit cast operators in
>   Kotlin, because the compiler tracks the is-checks for immutable values
>   and inserts (safe) casts automatically when needed:
>
> ```
> fun demo(x: Any) {
>     if (x is String) {
>         print(x.length) // x is automatically cast to String
>     }
> }
> ```

I don't understand what "smart casting" does in this example. There seems to be nothing that requires casting, as `x` will always be String and thus `x.length` will always work, no casting required. What is happening on the `print` line exactly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x` has a type `Any`, and that type doesn't have a `.length` property. However, since inside the `if` block, it's known that `x` is actually a `String`, it gets smart cast that type, and you can call methods and access properties of the `String` class on it.

The Java version of this code would look like this, you'd need an explicit cast to `String` even after doing the type check:

```
void demo(Object x) {
    if(x instanceof String) {
        System.out.print(((String) x).length());
    }
}
```

This is what Kotlin simplifies for you.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up, thank you. Coming from Python, I'm still wrapping my head around static typing.

Answer (score 3):

Without smart casting, you would have to tell the compiler the type is actually a String, since `length` does not exist on Any.

```
println((x as String).length)
```

With smart casting this isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Thank you. Coming from Python, I still have to wrap my head around statically typed languages - didn't realize that `x.length` has to throw an error when the type specified in the parameters isn't `string`.

Comment: You'd get an error in Python too if `x` wasn't a `String` when you call the method.

Comment: No, it would work perfectly fine, as it's dynamically typed. No checks concerning types are done whatsoever. If x wasn't string, the method woulf simply execute without the if clause.  And if it was string , no casting woulf be involved or necessary - all it does is check if the object x has an attribute length, without caring about the type at all. That's also why I was confused about Kotlin.